# Como mostrar el progreso de la subida de un fichero usando con boto3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

Estoy en una situación con una función de almacenamiento de documentos en una aplicación Django / Python (usando Boto3) donde también necesito proporcionar al usuario información sobre el progreso de carga.

¿Cómo haría para mostrar al usuario el progreso real en la vista usando Boto3 como el ejemplo de la foto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este codigo puedo ver el progreso en la consola del server pero no he podido lograr que se vea en la vista

```
class ProgressPercentage(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        self._size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
        self._seen_so_far = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def __call__(self, bytes_amount):
        # To simplify we'll assume this is hooked up
        # to a single filename.
        with self._lock:
            self._seen_so_far += bytes_amount
            percentage = (self._seen_so_far / self._size) * 100
            sys.stdout.write(
                "\r%s  %s / %s  (%.2f%%)" % (
                    self._filename, self._seen_so_far, self._size,
                    percentage))
            sys.stdout.flush()


transfer = S3Transfer(boto3.client('s3', 'us-west-2'))
# Upload /tmp/myfile to s3://bucket/key and print upload progress.
transfer.upload_file('/tmp/myfile', 'bucket', 'key',
                     callback=ProgressPercentage('/tmp/myfile'))
```